# How to get water from blender into three.js

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

I made transparent water using Blender, exported it with gltf, and then imported it with three.js, so the water property is not transparent.
just like a blue box.

how can i import transparent water in three.js?

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

 const loader = new GLTFLoader()
  loader.load(
    '../static/assets/model3.gltf',
    function (gltf) {
      console.log(gltf)
      const root = gltf.scene
      scene.add(root)
    },
    function (xhr) {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('An cerror occurred')
    }
  )
  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1)
  scene.add(ambientLight)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of Blender's materials, modifiers, and animation styles cannot be exported to any format. They exist only for rendering within Blender. If you're planning to export your scene, I'd recommend reviewing the [glTF addon documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html) very carefully. It explains the types of materials and animations that can be exported.

As of 2023, this generally means using Principled BSDF materials, and one of the following animation types: skinning, morph targets, and keyframe translation/rotation/scale animation. It's possible to make water-like [volumetric refraction effects with Principled BSDF](https://www.donmccurdy.com/2021/11/11/writing-volumetric-refraction-gltf/), as well, though I don't know of a guide for water specifically.